# Case origin updated automatically whenever customer replies

Tags: email2case

whenever a customer replies to an email that we send through salesforce using the XXX@gmail.com email address it is causing the case origin to be changed to email.
This should not happen.  The case origin should not automatically be changed when a customer replies.
For cases I have created a case(Email to case routing) that had origin phone. I then sent myself an email through the case.  The origin remained at phone. 
As soon as I replied to that email through outlook it wrote back to the case (as expected) but changed the case origin to email (not expected nor wanted).
there should be some way to change this so that the case origin is not automatically changed when an email reply comes in.Can any one help me on this issue

Comment: This is not the standard behavior. Check your customization code which may perform this override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a workflow rule to update the origin again which was previously `Phone`.

In the workflow rule check `origin` is changed and `Web Email` field is not null then update the `origin = Phone`